# Managing I2C address conflicts with multiple MCP23017 on the same bus

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, gpio, addressing

I'm using a Raspberry Pi with the I2C master and I successfully wired 8 different MCP23017 chips, each with their respective addresses by setting the last 3 bits of their 7 bit addresses. They are all working flawlessly.

My problem is that the basic addressing of the chips are permanently set to 0x20 to 0x27, which seems odd. After using `i2cdetect` I see so many other potential addresses.

My first question is:
If the chips are locked on the 0x20s will there be any conflict IF any another I2C device uses the same device address?

Secondly:
Is there a way to modify the basic addressing scheme (0x3*, 0x4*, 0x5*) to maximize all these potential addresses or are they permanently set for each device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My first question is: If the chips are locked on the 0x20s won't there be any conflict IF any another i2c device uses the same schemes?

Correct. Another slave device which uses address `0x20 - 0x27` *would* conflict with an existing [MCP23017](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/mcp23017.pdf) device using the same address within that address range, if they were connected on the same I<sup>2</sup>C bus. Each I<sup>2</sup>C slave needs a unique address on an I<sup>2</sup>C bus.

Two ways to mitigate a slave address conflict would be either spreading the devices across multiple I<sup>2</sup>C buses on the I<sup>2</sup>C master (e.g. the Raspberry Pi), or using an I<sup>2</sup>C multiplexer device on a single I<sup>2</sup>C bus (which effectively creates multiple I<sup>2</sup>C buses itself). [See below for another approach.]

> Secondly: Is there a way to modify the basic addressing scheme (0x3*, 0x4*, 0x5*) to maximize all these potential addresses. Or are they permanently set for each device?

This depends on the device (i.e. read their datasheet) but *typically* the I<sup>2</sup>C address, or the range of selectable I<sup>2</sup>C addresses, is fixed for each model of slave device.

One exception is where a slave device is totally programmable (e.g. some I<sup>2</sup>C slaves are actually PIC devices running firmware to make them into permanent I<sup>2</sup>C slaves) and in those cases, I have seen more flexibility about which addresses they can be programmed to use.

---

Edited to add: Another approach to avoid I<sup>2</sup>C bus address conflict, as kindly commented by @DoxyLover, is to use the [Linear Technologies I<sup>2</sup>C address translators](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/press-release/LTC4316-17-18.pdf) - [LTC4316](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4316), [LTC4317](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4317), [LTC4318](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4318). These devices re-write the I<sup>2</sup>C addresses "on-the-fly" between their input and output "channels". Effectively, they create new I<sup>2</sup>C bus segments, with a configurable pattern of (in theory, transparent) I<sup>2</sup>C address translation between the original and new I<sup>2</sup>C bus segments.

From their datasheets, they also add other features e.g. built-in "stuck bus" detection and voltage level translation. However, while they support common I<sup>2</sup>C features, there are a few which they don't support e.g. 10-bit addressing and Device ID. As always, read the datasheets.

In the context of the original question, an LTC4316 looks like it would be able to create a new I<sup>2</sup>C bus segment, where another set of (up to) eight MCP23017 devices could be connected. Let's assume that I<sup>2</sup>C addresses `0x30 - 0x37` are free on the I<sup>2</sup>C bus directly connected to the master, but the new set of MCP23017 devices need to use their fixed addresses `0x20 - 0x27`. The LTC4316 would be configured with a "translation byte" value of `0x10`.

On the LTC4316 "output" I<sup>2</sup>C bus segment, the new set of eight MCP23017 devices "see" their usual `0x20 - 0x27` I<sup>2</sup>C addresses, as they require. However on the "input" I<sup>2</sup>C bus segment where the I<sup>2</sup>C master is connected, the I<sup>2</sup>C master would address them using I<sup>2</sup>C addresses `0x30 - 0x37`, with the LTC4316 translating an address of `0x3n` on the "input" (master side) bus segment, to `0x2n` on the "output" (slave side) bus segment [where `n` = `0 - 7`].

Comment: There are also I2C address translation chips, that are placed between the bus and one (or more) devices that rewrite the address bits on the fly. For example http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4317

Comment: Thanks @DoxyLover - those are sufficiently new that I hadn't seen them! I will update this answer with your info - thanks again :-)

Comment: @Robotometry - In case you haven't seen the comment already, the device family mentioned by *DoxyLover* above might do what you want. I have updated my answer with links and a suggested scenario for using the LTC4316 as an example, in case that helps.