# Using 2 I2C RGB Color Sensors in Arduino

Tags: i2c, rgb

I want to use two I2C RGB color sensors (TCS3414-A) in Arduino, but I cannot figure how I change his adresses and I'm asking this because I want them both in use.

They come with 0x39 as default addresses, but as I want to change one to 0x40 and I don't know how to change it, I come here to ask you how I can solve that.

Regards,
Fábio.

Comment: You could have at least given us a link to the datasheet that you need help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. The TCS3414 is only available in slave address 0x39. There is the alternative parts 3413, 3415, and 3416 which have address 0x29, 0x49 and 0x59. Or you can use a i2c bus switch to have two i2c buses.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change one to 0x40

As *Passerby* said, you can't change the I<sup>2</sup>C address on the (now obsolete) [TCS3414](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/588/TCS3404_3414_TAOS137A_April%202011-519217.pdf) itself. The manufacturer produced different ICs with different I<sup>2</sup>C addresses. The list of I<sup>2</sup>C addresses on that range of colour sensors, is shown in the datasheet:

[image: TCS34xx I2C addresses]

Therefore if you need to access two of those ICs, you need to consider other options, including:

- Use multiple I<sup>2</sup>C buses, with one TCS3414 on each bus. Since you mention Arduino, you could put one sensor on the normal hardware I<sup>2</sup>C bus, and then use a [Software I2C master](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SoftwareI2CLibrary) library, to add another I<sup>2</sup>C bus for the second sensor.
- Use an I<sup>2</sup>C bus translator (see [this document](http://www.linear.com/docs/46537) from Linear Technology for examples). These ICs can re-write the I<sup>2</sup>C address to a second identical device "on-the-fly". My answer on [this very similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245539/managing-i2c-address-conflicts-with-multiple-mcp23017-on-the-same-bus) also applies here.
- Use either a "home brew" or ready-made I<sup>2</sup>C bus isolator or multiplexer, to switch a single I<sup>2</sup>C bus master to each of the colour sensors, one at a time. That would require you to switch the I<sup>2</sup>C bus to connect to sensor 1, before using that one. Then disconnect from sensor 1 and connect the master to sensor 2 (you may need to add a small delay here, depending on bus capacitance). Repeat as needed.